# Should you store returnurl in viewbag or viewmodel in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

We use the Post/Redirect/Get methodology and generally create a specific ViewModel for each of our Actions however ReturnUrl has always bugged me. What's the preferred method for persisting the ReturnUrl?

1. Adding it to ViewBag -and then redirecting with this e.g

   ```
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
       return RedirectToAction("login", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
   }
   ```

Or

2. store it in the ViewModel and output a hidden field with the value in? As we use ModelStateToTempData it transfers the value without additional thought.

The only reason I ask is because the default Microsoft templates have it using ViewBag on actions that use ViewModels

Comment: ViewModel no doubt. Why? because this is information for the view needed and its strongly typed - easier than to get confused with a generic ViewBag property. Plus the added bonus as I said is that its strongly typed and in your viewmodel so you can use the razor syntax to access it

Comment: That's interesting Ahmed, the only reason I ask is because the default Microsoft templates have it using ViewBag -with ViewModels

Comment: sure, but they are starter/basic templates. in the end it doesn't matter so much, but having a strongly typed approach Is always a win in the end for me and many others personally. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can store it in both, the question is *should* you?

I would say it depends on the complexity of your project, how many people are going to consume your code and extend it?

Another perspective is the concept - does your Model realistically encapsulate the ReturnUrl, or would you be tagging the ReturnUrl to it, 'just because'?

If the latter is the case, then I'd use ViewBag.